# Корректно ли в директиве v-for проходиться по 2 объектам

Tags: vue.js

Корректно ли в директиве `v-for` проходиться по 2 объектам:

```
v-for="article in sortedData, filterArticles"
```

Если нет, то как корректно можно записать следующий код:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" v-model="search">
<button class="btn btn-info" @click="setSortBy(sortBy)">Sort by id</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="article in sortedData, filterArticles" :key="article.id">
      <td>{{article.id}}</td>
      <td>{{article.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      articles: [],
      ...
    },
    computed: {
      filterArticles() {
        return this.articles.filter((article) => {
          return article.title.match(this.search);
        })
      },
      sortedData() {
        if (this.sortBy !== 'id') {
          return this.articles.slice();
        }
        return this.articles.sort((a, b) => (
          this.sortDirection * (b[this.sortBy] - a[this.sortBy])
        ));
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: А что, так можно делать? В [доке такого нет](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html). Или вы хотите, чтобы так работало?

Comment: Оно работает, просто для себя хочу знать можно ли так писать в будущем или нет, в документации я тоже не нашёл

Comment: перебор идет по последнему массиву. Поэтому, при такой записи, `sortedData` никакого участия в переборе не принимает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При просмотре [юнит-тестов](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/test/unit/features/directives/for.spec.js) можно узнать о способах применения директивы `v-for`  в различных ситуациях. К сожалению, описанного вами способа, мне найти не удалось.

---

При работе с массивами во Vue помните о том, что существуют два типа методов внесения изменений.

**1** [Методы](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), которые **изменяют оригинальный массив**, на котором они вызываются.

```
 push() pop() shift() unshift() splice() sort() reverse()
```

**2** И **не изменяющие** [методы](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5), они не вносят изменений в изначальный массив, а всегда возвращают новый массив.

```
filter() concat() slice()
```

И это вполне предсказуемое поведение для методов Javascript: например, [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). С той лишь разницей, что Vue оборачивает у наблюдаемого массива методы внесения изменений, чтобы они вызывали обновления представления.

Получается, что мы производим итерацию списка и при внесении условий в виде поисковой фразы и применения метода `filter()` мы не вносим изменений в оригинальный список, и данный метод Vue не вызывает обновления представления. Именно для того, чтобы увидеть изменения, определяем `computed` вычисляемое свойство `filteredArticles`. Вызываемый же метод `sort()` динамически перестраивает список `filteredArticles` и в примере ниже определен в методе-наблюдателе поля `watch`.

---

Ниже показан пример поиска в списке объектов по поисковой фразе (метод `filter`), а также сортировка с использованием выпадающего списка `select` (метод `sort`), с выбором направления сортировки.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    // Модель с записями.
    articles: [],
    ready: false,
    search: {
      query: '',
      where: 'title',
    },
    order: {
      column: 'id',
      direction: 'asc'
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // Вычисляемый список зависит от поискового запроса.
    // При изменении поискового запроса, список будет отфильтрован.
    // Метод filter() создаёт новый массив со всеми элементами,
    // прошедшими проверку.
    // https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Замены-в-массиве
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Возвращаемое_значение
    filteredArticles() {
      let query = this.search.query
      let where = this.search.where
      let filter = new RegExp(query, 'i')

      if (['title', 'description'].includes(where)) {
        return this.articles.filter(article => article[where].match(filter))
      }

      // Что-то пошло не так, возвращаем пустой массив.
      // Желательно еще в консоль что-то вывести.
      return []
    }
  },

  watch: {
    // Коллбэк будет вызываться каждый раз,
    // когда изменяется любое из свойств наблюдаемого объекта
    // https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch
    order: {
      handler: 'sortArticles',
      // независимо от глубины их вложенности
      deep: true,
      // коллбэк будет вызван сразу же после начала наблюдения
      immediate: true
    },
  },

  /**
   * Используем хук `mounted` для получения записей.
   */
  async mounted() {
    const response = await this.fetchArticles()

    this.articles = response.data
  },

  methods: {
    // Метод sort() `на месте` сортирует элементы массива.
    // https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Методы-внесения-изменений
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Возвращаемое_значение
    sortArticles(val, oldVal) {
      let direction = val.direction
      let column = val.column

      if (['id', 'title'].includes(column)) {
        if (direction === 'asc') {
          this.filteredArticles.sort((a, b) => a[column] > b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        } else if (direction === 'desc') {
          this.filteredArticles.sort((a, b) => a[column] < b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        }
      }

      // Что-то пошло не так.
      // Дальше сами придумайте.
    },

    fetchArticles() {
      this.ready = false

      // Импровизация получения данных ч/з ajax.
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.ready = true

          resolve({
            // Сортировка: id asc.
            data: [{
              id: 4,
              title: 'Voluptatem enim optio',
              description: 'Maiores adipisci et ut ipsam quo voluptas. Nulla atque et cupiditate odit.',
              image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
            }, {
              id: 8,
              title: 'Eum praesentium autem',
              description: 'Sint sapiente error eum. Et eveniet omnis deserunt sunt.',
              image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
            }, {
              id: 12,
              title: 'Voluptatem nihil voluptate',
              description: 'Odit consequatur accusantium excepturi minima velit. Et molestiae maiores ea.',
              image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
            }, {
              id: 18,
              title: 'Debitis illum ex eum',
              description: 'Commodi quia asperiores dignissimos sint quo tempore. Neque magni aut.',
              image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
            }],
            meta: {}
          })
        }, 2000)
      })
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.form__group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form__control {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.form__control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.alert-info {
  color: #2f6473;
  background-color: #def2f8;
  border-color: #d1edf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="filter__box">
    <div class="form__group">
      <label for="">Фильтровать</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="search.query" placeholder="Search" class="form__control" />
      <select v-model="search.where" class="form__control">
        <option value="title">Заголовок</option>
        <option value="description">Описание</option>
      </select>
      <!--
          Используем вычисляемое свойство, необходимость в кнопке отпадает.
          <button class="btn btn-info" @click="find">Найти</button>
      -->
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
      <label for="">Сортировать</label>
      <select v-model="order.column" class="form__control">
        <option value="id">Идентификатор</option>
        <option value="title">Заголовок</option>
      </select>
      <select v-model="order.direction" class="form__control">
        <option value="desc">по убыванию</option>
        <option value="asc">по возрастанию</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="!ready" class="alert alert-info">Загрузка записей, ожидайте 2 сек ...</div>

  <div v-if="ready && Boolean(filteredArticles.length)" class="articles">
    <template v-for="(article, index) in filteredArticles" :key="article.id">
            <article class="article">
                <h3 class="article__title">#{{ article.id }} {{ article.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
            </article>
        </template>
  </div>

  <div v-if="ready && !Boolean(filteredArticles.length)" class="alert alert-info">Нет информации для отображения.</div>
</div>
```

---

**Уточнение**. Ожидаемо, что при постраничной навигации с сервера приходят уже сортированные и фильтрованные данные.