# Как найти элементы массива по индексу из другого массива и вывести обновлённый список во Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Делаю фильтр по нажатию на кнопку должно найти у item категорию которая совпадает с категорией на кнопку, эти элементы оставить а остальные скрыть. Столкнулся с проблемой что в методе setSocialSortBy я сделал массив который содержит Index элементов у которых есть эта категория matchArr = [1,3,5 ...], но не получаеться теперь отфильтровать this.items по этому новому массиву matchArr. Как это можно сделать?

```
json который приходит с api:
    {name: 'title 1', category: 'cat 1'},
    {name: 'title 2', category: 'cat 2'},
    {name: 'title 3', category: 'cat 1'},
    {name: 'title 4', category: 'cat 2'} ...

 <button v-for="cat in cats" @click="setCatSortBy(cat)">{{cat}}</button>

    <div v-if="items.length > 0">
      <div v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>

    <script>
    export default {
    data() {
       items: [],
       cats: []
    },
    created () {
                this.fetchItems();
            },
    methods: {
    fetchItems() {
                    this.loading = true;
                    fetch("/api/items")
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {
                            this.items = res;

                            let catArr = [];
                            this.items.forEach((item) => {
                                catArr.push(item.category);
                            });

                            catArr.filter((value, index, arr) => {
                                if (arr.indexOf(value) === index) {
                                    this.cats.push(value.toLowerCase());
                                }
                            });
                        });
                },
               setCatSortBy(name) {
                    let matchArr = [];
                    this.items.filter((value, index) => {
                        if (value.category.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
                            matchArr.push(index);
                        }
                    });
                }
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Добавьте `json` хотя бы одного `item` из `/api/items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что стоит повторно обратиться к методам фильтрации, которые описаны в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/979176/256824).

Метод `filter()` не изменяет массив к которому применяется, он возвращает новый массив. Т.е. нужно сделать так:

```
this.items = this.items.filter(...)
```

Но если вы так сделаете, то из оригинального массива будут удалены отфильтрованные записи. И при дальнейшей фильтрации, этот массив будет "худать", пока не станет пустым.

Именно поэтому вводится промежуточный массив `filteredItems` для фильтрации, чтобы оригинальный оставался не тронутым.

> Вместо вычисляемого свойства, можно использовать ту же самую функцию в качестве метода. С точки зрения конечного результата, оба подхода делают одно и то же. Но есть важное отличие: вычисляемые свойства кешируются, основываясь на своих реактивных зависимостях. Вычисляемое свойство пересчитывается лишь тогда, когда изменится одна из его реактивных зависимостей. --[источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    // Модель с записями.
    items: [],
    // Модель с категориями.
    categories: [],
    ready: false,
    search: {
      category: '',
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // Вычисляемый список зависит от выбранной категории.
    // При изменении категории, список будет отфильтрован.
    // Метод filter() создаёт новый массив со всеми элементами,
    // прошедшими проверку.
    // https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Замены-в-массиве
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Возвращаемое_значение
    filteredItems() {
      let category = this.search.category

      return category
        ? this.items.filter(item => item.category === category)
        : this.items
    }
  },

  /**
   * Используем хук `mounted` для получения записей.
   */
  async mounted() {
    const response = await this.fetchArticles()

    this.items = response.data

    this.categories = this.makeCategoryList(this.items)
  },

  methods: {
    // Составляем список всех категорий.
    // Нам нужны только уникальные значения, поэтому
    // воспользуемся созданием массива ч/з Set.
    // За одно и отсортируем.
    makeCategoryList(items) {
      let cats = new Set()

      items.map(item => cats.add(item.category))

      return [...cats].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
    },

    fetchArticles() {
      this.ready = false

      // Импровизация получения данных ч/з ajax.
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.ready = true

          resolve({
            // Сортировка: id asc.
            data: [{
              id: 4,
              name: 'Voluptatem enim optio',
              category: 'cat 3'
            }, {
              id: 8,
              name: 'Eum praesentium autem',
              category: 'cat 2'
            }, {
              id: 12,
              name: 'Voluptatem nihil voluptate',
              category: 'cat 1'
            }, {
              id: 18,
              name: 'Debitis illum ex eum',
              category: 'cat 3'
            }],
            meta: {}
          })
        }, 2000)
      })
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.form__group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form__control {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.form__control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.alert-info {
  color: #2f6473;
  background-color: #def2f8;
  border-color: #d1edf6;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="filter__box">
    <div class="form__group">
      <label for="">Фильтровать по категории</label>
      <select v-model="search.category" class="form__control">
        <option value="">- Категория -</option>
        <option v-for="(category, index) in categories" :value="category">{{ category }}</option>
      </select>
      <!--
                Используем вычисляемое свойство, необходимость в кнопке отпадает.
            -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="!ready" class="alert alert-info">Загрузка записей, ожидайте 2 сек ...</div>

  <div v-if="ready && Boolean(filteredItems.length)" class="items">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" :key="item.id">
            <article class="article">
                <h3 class="article__title">#{{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}</h3>
            </article>
        </template>
  </div>

  <div v-if="ready && !Boolean(filteredItems.length)" class="alert alert-info">Нет информации для отображения.</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Рустам Гимранов, спасибо после вашего примера стало понятно в целом как работать с поиском и сортировкой во Vue

Comment: можете подсказать сокращённое условие в filteredItems() - return !!category - как записать если не сокращая, я не совсем понимаю что это за сравнение. if (category !== "" ) ?

Comment: Это двойное отрицание. Не удачный пример. Оно равнозначно записи `Boolean(category)`. Означает, что категория не должна быть пустой строкой, конкретно в этом случае. У select первый option имеет пустую строку. Сейчас подправлю. Здесь подробнее можете прочесть [1](https://riptutorial.com/ru/javascript/example/3047) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188946/)

Comment: спасибо теперь понял что там происходит